# How to combine parts of date from output of Date() in go

Tags: date, go, time

I'm using code similar to this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(now.Round(0))
    y, m, d := now.Date()
    fmt.Println(y, int(m), d)

}
```

Using this code how can I combine y, m and d so that it would be of format "yyyy-mm-dd" or like "2023-04-18"?

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `Format`:

```
func main(){
   now := time.Now()
   fmt.PrintLn(now.Format("2006-02-01"))
}
```

Format uses as reference the date of January, 2nd 2006, so for example:
`("02-01-2006")` means "DD-MM-YYY"